# Data view in html table from django views

Tags: html, django, database, django-views

I am trying to display data the tables from the database in some tables in an HTML template from django views. The problem is that the words are in a list and I want each word to be in each field in the table, How can I do that?

views.py:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       tp = request.POST.get('tp')
       ms = request.POST.get('mode_selection')
       if tp == "Download" or tp == "Preview":
           usr = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
           if ms=='2':
        data=WordDifferentTable.objects.filter(user=usr).values_list('word1','word2',word3', 'word4', 'word5', 'result')
        hds = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4', 'word5', 'result']
        elif ms=='3':
            data = LogicAnaloguiesTable.objects.filter(user=usr).values_list('word1', 'word2', 
       'word3', 'word4', 'word5', 'result', 'distance_to_word12')
            hds = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4', 'word5', 'result', 
       'distance_to_word12']
        elif ms=='4':
            data = SimilarWInContextTable.objects.filter(user=usr).values_list('word1', 
            'word2', 'word3', 'word4', 'word5', 'distance_to_word12', 'distance_to_word13', 
            'distance_to_word23')
            hds = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4', 'word5', 'distance_to_word12', 
            'distance_to_word13', 'distance_to_word23']
        else:
            data = WordsTable.objects.filter(user=usr).values_list('word1', 'word2', 'word3', 
            'word4', 'word5',)
            hds = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3', 'word4', 'word5',]

    return render (request, "base.html",context)
else:
    return render (request, "base.html")
```

HTML table:

```html
{% if data %}
<div style="padding-top: 30px" class="row">
    <h3 align="center">Preview</h3>
    <table style="border: 1px solid #dddddd;">
         <thead>
            <tr style="border: 1px solid;">
                {% for h in hds %}
                    <th style="border: 1px solid;">{{h}}</th>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody style="border: 1px solid;">
            {% for d in data %}
            <tr>
              {% for word in data %}
              <td style="border: 1px solid;">{{ word }}</td>
              {% endfor %}
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
         </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>
 {% endif %}
```

An example of how the data is shown, I want each word to be in each field:
[image]

Comment: Please indent, use proper spacing and naming convention in your code. And where's the first `if` statement? For the given code block you're passing a empty `context` to template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you iterate over `data` you get tuples, you need to iterate over each tuple to get your table cells

```
{% for d in data %}
  <tr>
    {% for word in data %}
      <td style="border: 1px solid;">{{ word }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I added your suggestion, but I am getting something different, maybe I did something wrong, can you check please?

Comment: @enekovalero `for word in d` not `for word in data` in your nested loop